# How to install JBoss on Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jboss-tools

installation JBoss Tools 4.11.0.Final through Eclipse Marketplace does not work. Manually install to give a lot of errors... On the last step installation in the window "Install Details", I get following message (Details):

> "Eclipse JSON Editor and Tools" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.
> "Mylyn WikiText AsciiDoc" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.
> "WST JSON Core" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.
> "Mylyn WikiText AsciiDoc UI" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.

If I'm correctly understand, need remove all conflicting plugins? Tell me please, what need to do and how to install JBoss Tools?

Comment: What installation did you start with?

Comment: @nitind I have Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers. Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0); jdk-11.0.2 (windows-x64); And also installed Spring Boot and Tomcat, but them for some reason I don't see from menu installation. For instal JBoss i'm used panel: Help -> Install New Software and link http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/updates/

Comment: I made [screenshots step by step with all of errors](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aLOSjbZM8V2T7vlCPIT9ewFXIpK7f5rw?usp=sharing). Available on google drive.

Comment: Hi @VitaliyM.V. , you're using the latest stable update site which is compatible with 2022-06 release, so as you're using 2019-03, the errors seems legit ( 3 years differences ).
so two solutions : 
- use eclipse 2022-06
- use the JBoss update site that is compatible with 2019-03. from the archives (https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/archives.html) it should be the 4.19.1.Final. the offline zip is here https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/2021-03/4.19.1.Final.html#zips. and the update site is https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/composite/4.19.1/